# Generalizing the code for tensor

Tags: matrix, tensors

$ f $ is a real antisymmetric matrix (here for simplicity I have considered $ d = 2 $), where $ 2*d $ is the dimension of the matrix.
$$f=\begin{bmatrix}0 & f_{12} & f_{13} & f_{14}\\
-f_{12} & 0 & f_{23} & f_{24}\\
-f_{13} & -f_{23} & 0 & f_{34}\\
-f_{14} & -f_{24} & -f_{34} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am taking the upper triangular part of the matrix and create an array. The new index is:
$$new=\left[\left(a-1\right)d\right]+b$$
The new matrix will be:
$$f_{new}=\begin{pmatrix}f_{12}\\
f_{13}\\
f_{23}\\
f_{14}\\
f_{24}\\
f_{34}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f_{1}\\
f_{2}\\
f_{3}\\
f_{4}\\
f_{5}\\
f_{6}
\end{pmatrix}$$
So f is a 6X1 vector now.
I have following relations.
$$h_{\left(bi,ja\right)}=\left(f_{bi}f_{ja}+I_{bi}I_{ja}\right)$$

It is forming in such a way that:
$$h_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}h_{1i,j2}\\
h_{1i,j3}\\
h_{2i,j3}\\
h_{1i,j4}\\
h_{2i,j4}\\
h_{3i,j4}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$i,j,k,l=1:2*d$$

I have written a code for the above problem. But it is only valid for d=2, Is there a way to generalize it for any dimension. Code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Format[\[Delta][a_, b_]] := Subscript[\[Delta], a, b]

\[Delta][a_, b_] := KroneckerDelta[a, b]
d = 2;

orth = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[2*d]];

orthx = Transpose[orth];

fmat1 = Block[{b, n = 2*d}, b = Riffle[ConstantArray[1, n/2], 0];
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> b, Band[{2, 1}] -> -b}, {n, n}]];

fmat2 = Normal@fmat1;

bigf = orth . fmat2 . orthx;

MatrixForm[bigf];

takeUpper1[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
  Join @@ Table[
    mat[[i, j]], {i, Length[mat]}, {j, i + 1, Length[mat]}];

fnew = takeUpper1[bigf];

MatrixForm[fnew];

h[b_, i_, j_, 
  a_] := (z[b, i]*z[j, a]) + (\[Delta][b, i]*\[Delta][j, a])

hmat = {{h[1, i, j, 2], h[1, i, j, 3], h[2, i, j, 3], h[1, i, j, 4], 
    h[2, i, j, 4], h[3, i, j, 4]}};

hmatR = Transpose[hmat];

MatrixForm[hmatR];
```

It would be great if I get a general way to create hmat. Right now I am writing each entries as above.

Comment: Why is qmat2 an {8,8,8,8} array instead of a {4,4,4,4} one? 
(why 2*d instead of d?)

Comment: @user3257842 In the code I have started with d=2 and hence my f will be of size 2d X 2d This is same as 4 X 4

Comment: Oh I see. In the post you refereed to d as the dimension ( d = 4), but in the code you set d = 2 and used  2*d as the dimension.

Comment: @user3257842 You are right. Sorry about that. Is there a way to generalise this

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I'm seeing is that you flatten the (upper-triangular) part of the matrix into a 1-dimentional array, tough in your operations it would be better suited to maintain the multidimensional tensor structure. (Ie. your "double-lettered" indices work better as simple groups of normal indices.)

Any tensor formula expressed in "Ricci notation" such as:

$$p_{\left(ba\right),\left(mn\right)}=q_{ijkl}h_{\left(bi,ja\right)}s_{\left(mk,ln\right)}$$

can be written in Mathematica using a combination of `TensorProduct`, `TensorTranspose` and `TensorContract`. Tough calculating the correct translation can be tedious. There should really be a library for this sort of thing.

I'm going to assume $q$ is a fully antisymmetric rank-$4$ tensor. In this case we can translate to:

```
p = TensorContract[
 h\[TensorProduct] q\[TensorProduct] s, 
  {{2,5},{3,6},{7,10},{8,11}}]
```

While this formula is correct, it is however, inefficient. Formulas work faster and with less memory if the tensor-contraction is done as early as possible and the tensor product is done as late as possible. We can rewrite the formula as:

```
p = TensorContract[ TensorContract[
   h\[TensorProduct]q, {{2, 5}, {3, 6}}]\[TensorProduct]s, {{3, 6}, {4, 7}}]
```

Our full code becomes:

```
RandomSymmetrizedArray[dims_, sym_, dist_] := 
 Normal@SymmetrizedArray[_ :> RandomVariate[dist], dims, sym];

d = 4;

f[a_, a_] := 0;
f[a_, b_] := -f[b, a] /; (a > b)
fMat  = Array[f, {d, d}]
Id = IdentityMatrix[d];
q  = RandomSymmetrizedArray[{d,d,d,d}, 
   Antisymmetric[All], NormalDistribution[0, 1]];

h = fMat \[TensorProduct] fMat + Id \[TensorProduct] Id;
s = fMat \[TensorProduct] fMat + Id \[TensorProduct] Id;
p = TensorContract[ TensorContract[
   h\[TensorProduct]q, {{2, 5}, {3, 6}}]\[TensorProduct]s, {{3, 6}, {4, 7}}]
```

This should work for any $d$. You can write the formula as a function of $d$ for higher modularity .

The "core" of the code is the bottom three lines/formulas for `h`, `s` and `p`, into which you can plug in any values for `fMat` , `Id` and `q`. With `fMat`and `Id` being `{d,d}`-sized arrays and `q` being a `{d,d,d,d}`-sized array.